# Insertion sort on an array of objects with javascript

Tags: javascript, node.js, algorithm, computer-science

I have this array with objects that look like this

```
{
 n: 15,
 color: "red"
}
```

I am trying to sort it with the below function

```
async insertionSort() {
      let len = this.array.length;
      let value;
      let i;
      let j;
      //let current;
      // let arr = this.array;

      for (i = 0; i < len; i++) {
        value = this.array[i].n;
        //current = this.array[i];
        for (j = i - 1; j > -1 && this.array[j].n > value; j++) {
          //arr[j + 1] = arr[j];
          // HF.arraySwap(this.array, this.array[j + 1], this.array[j]);
          this.array[j + 1] = this.array[j];
        }
        // arr[j + 1] = value;
        HF.arraySwap(this.array, this.array[j + 1], this.array[i]);
        await HF.sleep();
      }
    }
```

** I cant use array.sort(...) because i am trying to make a visualization of the algorithm, i am using objects in order to change the color of the bars i am rendering on the screen **
<s>When i hit the second for loop i get an error of "Cannot read property 'n' of undefined", when i run it with just numbers it works fine but when i try it with objects it gives the error</s>.I know now i am running out of the array, is there a way i can overcome this and still sort the array of objects? Also, i am using VueJS to display all of this

Comment: Any reason you are not using [sort](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort), what does your array look like and what output do you want?

Comment: I am trying to make a visualizer of the sorting algorithm, the array is just a list of about 30 objects that look exactly like the one mentioned. I need them to be objects so that i can change the color of the elements during the sorting, the function is async so that i can pause between action and behind it i am using splice to move elements in the array.

Comment: Your `j` loop simply runs out of the array.

Comment: Which sorting method do you want to visualize?

Comment: On a second thought, it is not that simply: the `array[j+1]=array[j]` part indefinitely extends the array, replicating the element where the loop started. You may see some browser limitation, normally such code would die on running out of memory. Check again how this sorting is supposed to work, I think the code would sort in decreasing order even after fixing; is that intended?

Answer (score 0):

On the first iteration `i=0`, you start second loop with value `j=i-1` which is -1. Array doesn't contain item with index -1: `array[-1]` is `undefined`. As soon as JavaScript can compare variables of different types it works with numbers because comparison of number and undefined won't trigger an error

By the way you can use [Array.proototype.sort](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort) method, it will look like:

```js
console.log(myArr.sort((a,b) => a.n - b.n))
```

```html
<script>
const myArr = [
    { n: 1, color: "red" },
    { n: 44, color: "orange" },
    { n: 13, color: "yellow" },
    { n: 8, color: "green" },
    { n: 2, color: "blue" }
  ];
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try against this.array[i].n write this.array[i][n]
And against this.array[j].n write this.array[j][n]

Comment: this is the same as using the dot notaion

Answer (score 0):

Is there any reason why not use sort method like this?:

```
  const arr = [
    { n: 10, color: "red" },
    { n: 20, color: "yellow" },
    { n: 15, color: "black" },
    { n: 7, color: "white" },
    { n: 23, color: "blue" }
  ];

  const ascSorted = arr.sort((a, b) => a.n - b.n); 
  const descSorted = arr.sort((a, b) => b.n - a.n);

  console.log(ascSorted);
  // [
  //   { n: 7, color: "white" },
  //   { n: 10, color: "red" },
  //   { n: 15, color: "black" },
  //   { n: 20, color: "yellow" },
  //   { n: 23, color: "blue" }
  // ];
```